# Get string from UTF8 (Invalid URI: There is an invalid sequence in the string)

Tags: c#, utf-8

Could you please help me understand why second line in following code throws exception?

```
string line1 = Uri.UnescapeDataString("Disk:%2FFolder");
string line2 = Uri.UnescapeDataString("Disk:%C0%AFFolder");
```

Maybe there is some other function which is able to decode "Disk:%C0%AFFolder" successfully?

Comment: FYI: This has absoutely nothing to do with UTF-8

Comment: "%c0%af" is an illegal Unicode representation of "/." <- Maybe has something to do with it [source](http://webhacking.org.ua/042.htm)

Comment: %2F and %C0%AF both represent '/' using UTF-8, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent quite a lot of time trying to find answer to my question.
In the end I gave up and decided to write decoder myself.

So this is it. If you want to decode UTF-8 bytes (which might contain overlong sequences) consider using code below:

```
    private static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int index = 0;

        while (index < bytes.Length)
        {
            if ((bytes[index] & 0x7F) == bytes[index])
            {
                Int32 code = bytes[index];
                byte[] codeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(code);
                builder.Append(UnicodeEncoding.UTF32.GetString(codeBytes));
                index += 1;
            }
            else if (((bytes[index] & 0xDF) == bytes[index]) && (index + 1) < bytes.Length
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 1] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 1]))
            {
                Int32 code = ((bytes[index + 0] & 0x1F) << 06) +
                             ((bytes[index + 1] & 0x7F) << 00);
                byte[] codeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(code);
                builder.Append(UnicodeEncoding.UTF32.GetString(codeBytes));
                index += 2;
            }
            else if (((bytes[index] & 0xEF) == bytes[index]) && (index + 2) < bytes.Length
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 1] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 1])
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 2] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 2]))
            {
                Int32 code = ((bytes[index + 0] & 0x0F) << 12) +
                             ((bytes[index + 1] & 0x7F) << 06) +
                             ((bytes[index + 2] & 0x7F) << 00);
                byte[] codeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(code);
                builder.Append(UnicodeEncoding.UTF32.GetString(codeBytes));
                index += 3;
            }
            else if (((bytes[index] & 0xF7) == bytes[index]) && (index + 3) < bytes.Length
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 1] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 1])
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 2] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 2])
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 3] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 3]))
            {
                Int32 code = ((bytes[index + 0] & 0x07) << 18) +
                             ((bytes[index + 1] & 0x7F) << 12) +
                             ((bytes[index + 2] & 0x7F) << 06) +
                             ((bytes[index + 3] & 0x7F) << 00);
                byte[] codeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(code);
                builder.Append(UnicodeEncoding.UTF32.GetString(codeBytes));
                index += 4;
            }
            else if (((bytes[index] & 0xFB) == bytes[index]) && (index + 4) < bytes.Length
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 1] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 1])
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 2] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 2])
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 3] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 3])
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 4] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 4]))
            {
                Int32 code = ((bytes[index + 0] & 0x03) << 24) +
                             ((bytes[index + 1] & 0x7F) << 18) +
                             ((bytes[index + 2] & 0x7F) << 12) +
                             ((bytes[index + 3] & 0x7F) << 06) +
                             ((bytes[index + 4] & 0x7F) << 00);
                byte[] codeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(code);
                builder.Append(UnicodeEncoding.UTF32.GetString(codeBytes));
                index += 5;
            }
            else if (((bytes[index] & 0xFD) == bytes[index]) && (index + 5) < bytes.Length
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 1] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 1])
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 2] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 2])
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 3] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 3])
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 4] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 4])
                                                             && ((bytes[index + 5] & 0xBF) == bytes[index + 5]))
            {
                Int32 code = ((bytes[index + 0] & 0x01) << 30) +
                             ((bytes[index + 1] & 0x7F) << 24) +
                             ((bytes[index + 2] & 0x7F) << 18) +
                             ((bytes[index + 3] & 0x7F) << 12) +
                             ((bytes[index + 4] & 0x7F) << 06) +
                             ((bytes[index + 5] & 0x7F) << 00);
                byte[] codeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(code);
                builder.Append(UnicodeEncoding.UTF32.GetString(codeBytes));
                index += 6;
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Wrong UTF-8 format");
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string source = "Disk:%FC%80%80%80%80%AFFolder";
        byte[] bytes = HttpUtility.UrlDecodeToBytes(source);
        string result = GetString(bytes);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

[URLS ares 7bits ASCII](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). W3schools says :

> URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the [ASCII character-set](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp).

%C0 and %AF are not 8bits encoded. That's why it's not decoded by  `Uri.UnescapeDataString`.

Comment: Thank you. How do I get string from "Disk:%C0%AFFolder"?